# Javscript detect the state of a div so I can toggle between 2 functions? (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I have a sidebar and I have 2 functions.
One opens it and the other one closes it.

Here are the two functions.

```
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

I want to create a condition between both so I can toggle them but for that I need to detect if it's opened or closed.

How can I detect it so I can create a toggle function calling the functions above?

Comment: Store the state in a JS variable, and update it when needed.

Comment: Use a class (`.opened`, or `.closed`) with the necessary styling rules and toggle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need two functions. You can do this with just one CSS class and one function that toggles that one class on the sidebar element.

To do this, add the default `width` of `0%` on the sidebar and then create another class, lets call it `.sidebarToggle`, that changes the `width` to `100%`.

In javascript, you just need one function, lets call it `toggleSidebar()` that just toggles the `.sidebarToggle` class. This way, you not only need less code but also don't need to worry about checking whether the sidebar is opened or closed.

#### A Better Solution

A better approach is to change the `transform` property of the sidebar instead of the `width`. Changing `transform` property, in this case, is better as compared to changing `width`, because if you change the `width`, you will have to handle the:

- resizing of the child elements of the sidebar as the sidebar's `width` is increased or decreased.
- remove the left or right `padding` (if there's any) on the sidebar when the `width` of the sidebar is `0px` or `0%`. If you don't remove the `padding`, sidebar will not completely hide on `0px` or `0%` `width`.

With `transform`, you don't need to worry about the above mentioned points because, instead of resizing, we just translate the sidebar from one point to another.

Animating `transform` property is also more efficient as compared to animating the `width` property because changing `transform` property doesn't causes the browser to go through Layout and Paint steps of its critical rendering path whereas changing the `width` property will cause the browser to again go through these steps.

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebarToggle');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #666;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  position: absolute;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
}

span {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.sidebarToggle {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <span>Item 1</span>
  <span>Item 2</span>
  <span>Item 3</span>
  <span>Item 4</span>
</div>

<button>Toggle Sidebar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is best done with classes. That way, stying is better separated from behaviour and there is even a [toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp) function built in:

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
   document.getElementById("myNav").classList.toggle("width100");
};
```

```css
#myNav {
   background-color: red;
   display: block;
   height: 100px;
   width: 0%;
}

#myNav.width100 {
   width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav id="myNav"></nav>
<button id="button">Toggle</button>
```